# Why is returnUrl needed here at login? Url.IsLocalUrl(string returnUrl)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Found in one of the examples where url is used. Why use an app url when returnUrl is always == null? Why is it necessary to check the condition when the user logs in, if I can do without it. Can you cite situations where this is necessary?

> if (! String.IsNullOrEmpty (model.ReturnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl
> (model.ReturnUrl)).

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        return View(new LoginViewModel { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result =
                await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, true);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReturnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Wrong password or name");
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }






public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Remember?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
}


@model Test.ViewModels.LoginViewModel

<h2>Login to the application</h2>
<form method="post" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login"
      asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
    <div>
        <label asp-for="Email"></label><br />
        <input asp-for="Email" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Email"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label asp-for="Password"></label><br />
        <input asp-for="Password" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Password"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label asp-for="RememberMe"></label><br />
        <input asp-for="RememberMe" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign in" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say user hits any Authorized endpoint of your application while his session was expired and the app redirects him to the login page but also passes the returnUrl (the endpoint user was trying to access) to the login Action. Now after the successful authentication, user can be redirected back to the url he was trying to access. This happens in all modern applications.

Url.IsLocalUrl() returns true for URLs like /Product/Details/1234 and false for URLs like http://www.someurl.com/Product/Details/1234

If you don't want this check you can remove it but the application will not remain user friendly:

```
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");              
}
```